# Function in async function chain not being called

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I'd like to update the user's data in Firestore whenever they log in and am using the following code to do so. For some reason, the code doesn't work (see comments) and doesn't create a custom `User` object from `firebase.User`. Why is this happening/how do I fix this? I'm not getting any errors.

### Code that is called to log in

```
async emailLogIn(email: string, password: string) {
  return this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then( async (credential) => {
      this.analytics.logEvent('logged_in', { method: 'email' });

      const firebaseUser = credential.user;
      if(firebaseUser) {
        const user = await this.createUserFromFirebaseUser(firebaseUser);
        console.log(user); // This doesn't print anything
        this.updateUserData(user);
        if(!firebaseUser.emailVerified) {
          this.sendEmailVerification();
        }
      }
    });
}
```

### Code that is convert `firebase.User` to `User` (doesn't work)

```
async createUserFromFirebaseUser(firebaseUser: firebase.User): Promise<User> {
  console.log('createUserFromFirebaseUser()');
  const currentUser = await this.user.toPromise();
  console.log(currentUser); // This doesn't print anything

  if(currentUser)
    return currentUser;

  const user: User = {
    uid: firebaseUser.uid,
    email: firebaseUser.email,
    displayName: firebaseUser.displayName,
    settings: {
      language: 'English',
      isPrivate: false,
      newFountainNotification: true,
      userFountainNotification: true,
      feedbackNotification: true,
      units: 'Metric'
    }
  }
  
  return user;
}
```

### Getting user data from Firestore

```
this.user = this.auth.authState.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destroy),
  switchMap( (user) => {
    if(user) {
      return (this.firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).valueChanges() as Observable<User>)
    } else {
      return of(null);
    }
  })
);
```

Comment: The issue may be in the line where you created the new user object. You defined the type as `User`. Does the User interface supports all the property you are adding? Try making the type `any` and see if that works.

Comment: @AbrarHossain Yes, the ```user``` variable has all the properties of ```User```. I don't think that's an issue, since the line before it isn't executing (```console.log(currentUser);```)

Comment: So it's printing`undefined`? What's `this.user` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to be an issue with using `this.user.toPromise()`

This is the code that works:

```
return this.user.pipe(
    take(1),
    map( (currentUser) => {
      if(currentUser)
        return currentUser;

      const user: User = {
        uid: firebaseUser.uid,
        email: firebaseUser.email,
        displayName: firebaseUser.displayName,
        settings: {
          language: 'English',
          isPrivate: false,
          newFountainNotification: true,
          userFountainNotification: true,
          feedbackNotification: true,
          units: 'Metric'
        }
      }
      
      return user;
    })
  ).toPromise()
```